# Monitor Dell workstation power supply and hard disk SNMP

Tags: dell, snmp, oid

I've been trying and trying to monitor workstation power supplies and hard disk statuses with SNMP. I can't get any SNMP information from the workstations but I have successfully been able to get power supply information from Dell servers, such as, Poweredge 720.

I've tried installing various tools like OpenManage and it's flavors to no avail.

Has anyone had any experience monitoring this kind of informaiton with SNMP? Workstations model is Dell Precision T36.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the OMCI on the Precision T36 from here:  http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1773.openmanage-client-instrumentation-omci.aspx

You'll need that installed.  The SNMP "system state group" will have power supply info for instance.  You can find the full references here: ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_software/esuprt_client_sys_mgmt/esuprt_client_sys_mgmt_opnmang_clnt_instr/dell-opnmang-clnt-instr-v8.2.1_Reference%20Guide2_en-us.pdf

You'll need OMCI in order to report on things correctly via SNMP on a workstation.

Comment: So I have OMCI installed on a workstation and have rebooted. I found that 10892.mib has the definitions for systemstategroup but when I try to actually snmp GET the information the machine responds with "No Such Object." I've installed the latest OMCI from the Dell website released on the 13th of October. I've been using the free ireasoning mib browser for all of my general SNMP testing and for the most part things work, but this one I am having the most trouble with. Any idea if there is something else that needs to be done for this group to work? The Windows SNMP service is running.

Comment: How did you install OMCI?  Did you do custom and choose SNMP and Standards-based?

Answer (score -1):

1. [Google is a really helpful resource](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/precision-t3600?driverId=YTD6R&osCode=W764&fileId=3301040243&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM).
2. You've done it on Dell servers and don't understand why you can't figure it out with Dell workstations? Maybe because Dell servers and Dell workstations aren't the same thing.
3. [Use the right tool for the job](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/precision-t3600?driverId=YTD6R&osCode=W764&fileId=3301040243&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM).
4. For the future, Google or your vendor's support line should be your *first* resource, not your last...

Comment: wow, sorry for asking for advice on a help site. my humblest apologies

Comment: Well we expect you to do some work on your own, like Googling for an answer, calling the vendor for assistance, and not equating server management to workstation management. I've never used a Dell management tool for workstations but I found the answer in about 90 seconds using Google. My point being, you could have done the same and at the very least, when you have a question about a particular vendor you should ask the vendor first.

Comment: This is a help site, for people who *do* know how to help themselves and are stuck on something, or are having trouble weighing alternatives. It is a good idea to try search engines and vendor documentation first, of course.